# Can Clonezilla work with Windows striped volume?

Tags: windows, disk-image, software-raid, clonezilla

Let's assume I have striped volume in Windows 11 (two disks).

Will Clonezilla be able to create and later restore images of both disks, so Windows will still recognize them properly as striped volume?

Answer (score 1):

From Clonezilla FAQ article
[Does Clonezilla support RAID ?](https://drbl.org/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/65_Clonezilla_support_RAID.faq#65_Clonezilla_support_RAID.faq)

> Clonezilla does support hardware RAID, if your RAID device is seen as
> /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, /dev/hda, /dev/hdb, /dev/cciss/c0d0... on
> GNU/Linux. Clonezilla does support this.
>
> On the other hand, if it's Linux software RAID, no, Clonezilla does
> not support that.

Clonezilla RAID support seems to be Linux-oriented, so I wouldn't advise
using it on Windows.

However, the data in a RAID 0 (striped volume) can be backed up as a single
partition, using any backup program.
Restoring the data to a any RAID 0 disk-set as folders and files does not
require the disk allocation to be exactly as when backed up.